# Transferring Hard Drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I wanted to ask this question before I got ahead of myself, but is it possible to take a hard drive from another computer and put it into a new one, and be able to boot from it? I have checked what cable the drive uses, and it is SATA. I'm just wondering if it'll work on a new computer with different hardware specs, since I plan on building a gaming PC when I can afford the parts.

Comment: What computer(s), what OS? Recent Windows can do this, Macs always could, nix I'm not sure. Licensing on Win may be an issue, but not on Mac or nix.

Comment: A drive from computer A needs drivers for computer B for it to start. OEM licenses on A generally won’t activate on B so you need a new license key as well.

Comment: John is mostly correct for Windows (it is possible to transfer a license from one machine to another, but it may require calling Microsoft); even if the specs on the two computers were identical, Windows _will_ detect that "the hardware has changed", and will probably require reactivation.

Comment: The PC I will be building will not have a drive, because I plan on taking the drive from my current PC and putting it into the newly-built one, if that makes sense.

Comment: If you prep the drive first using sysprep that is built into W7 and above, but will not activate the license due to different hardware.

Comment: How do I trigger sysprep?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But If you're building a gaming PC, most likely you will have a newer faster SSD. Instead, use drive cloning software like Macrium Reflect or similar to transfer your old drive contents to the new one.